# docker run does not work from cronjob

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, cron

I got a cronjob set up on an AWS EC2 instance which is supposed to start a docker container:

```
15 0 * * * docker run -e ENVIRONMENT=dev myrepo/my-image-name
```

I can see in the cron log it's attempting to run the job, but the container does not get run. Tried with sudo, still does not run. What could be reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cron does not know about environment variables, e.g. $PATH - so it cannot find `docker` to run. Should specify full path: `/usr/bin/docker`, like this:

```
15 0 * * * /usr/bin/docker run -e ENVIRONMENT=dev myrepo/my-image-name
```

To those who wonder how to find where the `docker` lives: run `which docker` in your console.